# Can't use log4j on SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I apologize if my question has been already treated, but I've struggled with this issue for days and I've not found a solution so far.
Go to the point: I have a SpringBoot application, and I would like it to write in a log file.

This is my pom.xml file

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mycomp.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>scheduling-tasks</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>scheduling-tasks</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
         <exclusions>
       
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
             <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
         <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my log4j.xml:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
    <log4j:configuration>
    
    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    
       <param name="file" value="${log}/log.out"/>
       <param name="immediateFlush" value="true"/>
       <param name="threshold" value="debug"/>
       <param name="append" value="false"/>
       
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="conversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
       </layout>
    </appender>
    
    <logger name="log4j.rootLogger" additivity="false">
       <level value="DEBUG"/>
       <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>
    
    </log4j:configuration>
```

In the classes where I'd like to log, I imported org.slf4j.Logger and org.slf4j.LoggerFactory defined I field like this:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);
```

If I use the statement

```
log.info("write something");
```

it is logged into the Console but no files are created.
I'm pretty sure the configuration is ignored because I tried several log4j.xml files with differents layouts and nobody has worked.

Any suggestions are welcome? Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Stefano

Answer (score 0):

Your log level is set to debug but you are trying log.info . Can you try with the below and check:

```
<logger name="log4j.rootLogger" additivity="false">
   <level value="INFO"/>
   <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: thank you so much. Unfortunately it's the same, It seems ignoring the configuration

Comment: I've just added the entire pom.xml